# Problems when `oc cluster up`

Tags: openshift, okd

when i use `oc cluster up`,it cannot install all the component that it needs.

restart docker,nothing changed

enverionment

```
docker 1.13.1
OKD 3.11
CentOS 7.6
```

error logs

```
E0905 11:43:43.072885    7323 interface.go:34] Failed to install "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator": failed to install "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1
E0905 11:43:43.085253    7323 interface.go:34] Failed to install "openshift-apiserver": failed to install "openshift-apiserver": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1
E0905 11:43:43.101772    7323 interface.go:34] Failed to install "kube-proxy": failed to install "kube-proxy": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1
E0905 11:43:43.123500    7323 interface.go:34] Failed to install "kube-dns": failed to install "kube-dns": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1
I0905 11:43:43.123545    7323 interface.go:41] Finished installing "kube-proxy" "kube-dns" "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" "openshift-apiserver"
Error: [failed to install "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1, failed to install "openshift-apiserver": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1, failed to install "kube-proxy": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1, failed to install "kube-dns": Docker run error rc=1; caused by: Docker run error rc=1]
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem